# How to Identify the specific event, when user has locked/unlocked the iPhone5 device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, ios5.1

I have gone through many questions, but didn't get exactly how I'll get the lock/unlock event for iOS 5 and above.

From the various post, I understood that when user locks the screen in iOS 5 iPhone, socket connection is lost and for that we need to handle network connectivity part in background method `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`.

But is there an exact way to handle specifically lock/unlock event on iOS?
Because `applicationWillResignActive` method is called for screen locking/unlocking and other events, like exiting application by pressing home button or launching another application.

Is there any specific delegate method called **only** when iPhone screen is locked/unlocked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way of distinguishing in general why your app transitions to the background. There are some ways to detect, say, a phone call (`CTCallCenter` in the Core Telephony framework), but there's no way to tell that the device is locked specifically.